# emails queued and delivery failed on VPS

Tags: email, vps

i bought a new VPS through softlayer with cpanel and im having a few issues with my email

when i send an email to anyone using gmail, yahoo, hotmail, it gets queued and after around 72 hours it returns back with a delivery failed

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  theemail@gmail.com
    retry timeout exceeded
```

im using the cpanel mail and im using softlayer's default nameservers

```
ns1.softlayer.com
ns2.softlayer.com
```

and im my MX record i have

```
mail.mydoamin.com
```

Can someone tell me what must be wrong?